# Support of a measure having continuous density with respect to Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\Omega=R^d$ and let $\nu$ have a continuous density $f$ with respect to the Lebesgue
measure. Show that the support of $\nu$ is the closure of ${\{f > 0}\}$

Definition of support used:

Any measurable set A with $\nu(A^c)=0$ is called a support of $\nu$.

Comment: Note you have defined "a support," not "the support."  Does the definition go on to say "the support" is the intersection of all closed supports?

Comment: Yes it does actually.